# Custom colorAccent can't work in Settings application

Tags: android, settings, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am customizing Settings application based on Marshmallow source code;
Example: color of action bar, status bar, EditTextView, Dialog Button and so on.
After reading guide of material design,  I know modification of colorAccent can meet me.
So, I do as below:

```
<style name="Theme.SettingsBase" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Settings" />
<style name="Theme.Settings" parent="Theme.SettingsBase"> 
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

---

Unfortunately, it can't work, their color is still deep teal.

Source code: 
http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/packages/apps/Settings/res/values/themes.xml

Comment: what is the value of `@color/red`?

Comment: <color name="red">#F00</color>

Comment: I will look into this soon.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ishita Sinha. As you know, Settings is System application. So I build it with Android Source instead of Google Android SDK. And I found a strange thing: For demo I built in Android Studio with SDK , change of colorAccent can get expected result. As you know , Settings is built in Android Source directly. Next day, I will try from this point.

Comment: Oh! This is for an android-based OS? I only have experience with apps and stuff, but I've never worked with AOSP source code. I don't know how much help I can be to you. :(

Comment: Hello Ishita Sinha, it is my mistake, I found there is style override operation at other side.
By the way, colorPrimaryDark can't work because my device is lowRamDevice. PhoneWindow doesn't show status bar through checking it.
I have modified policy of PhoneWindow in my ROM.

Thanks.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem! Please post an answer and accept it so that others can benefit from it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is theme override operation first after you apply you own style, especially call of applyStyle/setTheme .

colorPrimaryDark can't work though Theme.Settings have set windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds because there is following code in PhoneWindow.java and ActivityManager.java:

```
   // PhoneWindow.java
protected ViewGroup generateLayout(DecorView decor) {  
  // Non-floating windows on high end devices must put up decor beneath the system bars and
  // therefore must know about visibility changes of those.
  if (!mIsFloating && ActivityManager.isHighEndGfx()) { // Shield off this flag if isFloating or lowEndGfx
      if (!targetPreL && a.getBoolean(
              R.styleable.Window_windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds,
              false)) {
          setFlags(FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS,
                  FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS & ~getForcedWindowFlags());
      }
  }
  ...
}


private WindowInsets updateColorViews(WindowInsets insets, boolean animate) {

    if (!mIsFloating && ActivityManager.isHighEndGfx()) {

        ...
    }

    ...
}

// ActivityManager.java
static public boolean isHighEndGfx() {
      return !isLowRamDeviceStatic() &&
              !Resources.getSystem().getBoolean(com.android.internal.R.bool.config_avoidGfxAccel);
  }

  /** @hide */
public static boolean isLowRamDeviceStatic() {
    return "true".equals(SystemProperties.get("ro.config.low_ram", "false"));
}
```

I just change the PhoneWindow's policy which doesn't check ro.config.low_ram property to Quickly achieve my expect.